# Can I use NativeActivity with ActivityGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, activitygroup, native-activity

I know `ActivityGroup` is deprecated.

But I am trying to combine user interface of `NativeActivty` with some Java/Android API `View`s.

I am trying to make one hybrid user interface where a part of the screen is from `NativeActivity`.

[I used this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3265352/703851) and tried `ActivityGroup` with some simple activities.

This work perfectly with any `Activity` (Even if I play video using VideoView).

But when I tried to load `NativeActivity` it not working. (I tried **[Teapot demo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/1b8ffe3331233ba4902d94670cd257e7df9ee09d/ndk/platforms/android-17/samples/Teapot)** from NDK samples).

By "not working" I mean  `window.getDecorView()` from native activity it always return transparent view, not actual content view.

How should I do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time I found a workaround for it, and works fine. but just for the ndk demos.

on your ActivityGroup sub class onCreate method, write the following code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocalActivityManager lam = getLocalActivityManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, TeapotNativeActivity.class);

    Window window = lam.startActivity("xxx", intent);

    // reflect call "willYouTakeTheSurface"
    NativeActivity callback = JavaCalls.callMethod(window.getDecorView(), "willYouTakeTheSurface");
    if (callback != null) {
        window.takeSurface(null);
        getWindow().takeSurface(callback);
        getWindow().takeInputQueue(callback);
    }


    setContentView(window.getDecorView());

}
```